# Building Web Based System With Graphical Presentation

Tags: php, web, graphics

I am new to this, really new. This is my first time to develop a web-based system with graphical presentation (visual representation). Actually I don't know where to start and how I should start. I need something like www.simpleerb.com where we can easily move the tables in the restaurant.

I like to know where to start? What engine it is using in order to develop something like this? I like to have a system where I can easily drag my visualize information in the table. For example, changing something in the time slot. Please help me as I don't have any knowledge on this. I only plan to use PHP + HTML + AJAX and some basic stuffs. But definitely cannot do this one. How can I achieve this?

Thank you guys, appreciate your help.

Comment: If you are having trouble finding tools that fit your goal either your knowledge is not enough to achieve your goal or you haven't researched enough.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt simple answer to your question, you have to learn much. On windows you can easy use XAMPP - http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html. Its simple apache server, include php, mysql, apache. And for some programing, i recomended you to start here: http://www.codecademy.com/learn - basic stuff of web development.
And for javascript, you can search for codecombat.com, its game for learning it.